# How to define Cartier divisor and Weil divisor on algebraic stack?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, divisors, algebraic-stacks, line-bundles

How to define Cartier divisor and Weil divisor on algebraic stack? Do they correspond to line bundles on stack like the case of schemes? In case of a Deligne-Mumford stack, can we have a simpler description?

Comment: Already there exist schemes such that Cartier divisor (classes) do not correspond to line bundles.

Comment: The appendix A of the paper "Shtukas and Taylor expansion of L functions" by Z, Yun and W. Zhang discusses intersection theory on DM stacks. Relevant references are also contained therein.

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to see Cartier divisors as generalized Cartier divisors (Mumford's terminology), that is pairs $(\mathcal L,s)$ where $\mathcal L$ is an invertible sheaf and $s$ a section. These pairs satisfy fppf descent (also genuine Cartier divisors) so the definition on algebraic stacks follows.

Comment: @Niels That notion is also what Bill Fulton calls a "pseudodivisor".  Of course this is an "actual" Cartier divisor if and only if $s$ is regular and invertible at every associated point.

Comment: @JasonStarr, thanks for your comment. I should have said "invertible sheaves" instead of "line bundles".

Comment: There is no bijection between Cartier divisor classes and invertible sheaves in the case of stacks (nor even for algebraic spaces).  This is what both @Niels and I are alluding to.  Already for the Deligne-Mumford stack $BG$ for $G$ a finite group like $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, the group of Cartier divisors classes is trivial, yet the group of invertible sheaves is the group of group homomorphisms from $G$ to the multiplicative group $\mathbb{G}_m$ (i.e., the Pontryagin dual group).  You can "correct" this by changing the definition of Cartier divisors a la Mumford / Fulton.